# Mail Sent to spam in ROR

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-4

Mail sent to spam folder. I don't understand the problem.

## Mailing Confirgation

```
# Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  #config/environments/development.rb
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :openssl_verify_mode => 'none',
      address: 'vps103.spsnetwork.net',
      port: 25,
      domain: 'mail.forestbankfoundation.org',
      authentication: :login,
      enable_starttls_auto: true,
      user_name: 'no-reply@forestbankfoundation.org',
      password: '********'
  }
```

## Mailer Action

```
class NewsLetterMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def newsletter_email(newsletter)
     @newsletter = newsletter
     mail(from: "no-reply@forestbankfoundation.org", to: @newsletter.email, subject: "New Letter For FBF Registartion", body: " Hello #{@newsletter.name} \n :Email: #{@newsletter.email}, \n Thank You For Registration Our News Letter" )
  end
end
```

Can someone figure this out. I am not understanding why this will be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think action_mailer has something to do with it buddy. Have a look at [this](http://www.activecampaign.com/help/improving-delivery/)

> Every receiving ISP is using different spam filtering techniques and
>   some ISP’s utilize some pretty crazy ideas to combat spam. So you will
>   undoubtedly have some mail filtered at some point during sending email
>   campaigns.